# Sign out from all sessions IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have an `IdentityServer4` instance that manages authentication and what I discovered is that my small implementation does not seem to be handling correctly a couple of things:

1) "Auto-logging off" after X number of minutes with no interaction, then a new action that has the `Authorized` attribute would return a 401 back.

2) Multiple browser session (i'm just duplicating tabs here) seem to be independent from each other therefore when I log out from one screen I still can do stuff on the other tab however I would have expected my API to reject any request since the user did sign off.

Due to the fact I'm using `MongoDB` as my persistence layer I chose to integrate the package https://github.com/alexandre-spieser/AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDbCore . My AccountController looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Show login page
/// </summary>
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    var viewModel = new LoginInputModel
    {
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}

/// <summary>
/// Handle postback from username/password login
/// </summary>
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberLogin, false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
            }

            return Redirect("~/");
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, AccountOptions.InvalidCredentialsErrorMessage);
    }

    // something went wrong, show form with error
    return View(model);
}

/// <summary>
/// Show logout page
/// </summary>
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(string logoutId)
{
    var logoutContext = await _interaction.GetLogoutContextAsync(logoutId);

    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();

    return Redirect(logoutContext.PostLogoutRedirectUri);
}
```

My question is that how to make SignInManager to somehow perform the sign in establishing the login duration like this:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/master/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L125

because it seems that this does not sign out even after closing the browser. Not sure why the token is not expired and whether I have to do something else to validate it /expire.

The second aspect of this question is how can I make, if that's possible, one sign out to invalidate that session across all browser tabs/instances.

In my StartUp.cs I have the following configuration:
var authority = Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:Authority").Value;

```
        Logger.Info($"Using authority {authority} for authentication...");

        var identityDatabaseName = Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:DatabaseName").Value;

        Logger.Info($"Using {identityDatabaseName} MongoDB database for identity server data...");

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, MongoIdentityRole>()
                .AddMongoDbStores<ApplicationUser, MongoIdentityRole, Guid>(connectionString, identityDatabaseName)
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = authority;
            options.Audience = "myapi";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Thanks!